# Controlling Outlook Calendar using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I'm developing a project that I need to set in a group calendar some meetings. Then the users will propose new times according to then agendas and then with VBA I need to export that new time proposes to a database.

Some one have any idea of how can I do this?

Thanks!

I already know how to input a meeting using VBA macro. But my main problem is how to export to a database the new time proposes that group members proposed.

Comment: It may be possible as described here https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/.

Comment: [ERROR in objMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True).ProposedStartTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75986902/error-in-objmeeting-getassociatedappointmenttrue-proposedstarttime)

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle the [NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event of the `Application` class. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID represented by the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Also you may find the [Items.ItemChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemchange) event helpful. It is fired when an item in the specified collection is changed. For example:

```
Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 
 
Public Sub Initialize_handler() 
 Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items 
End Sub 
 
Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object) 
 Dim prompt As String 
 If VBA.Format(Item.Start, "h") >= "17" And Item.Sensitivity <> olPrivate Then 
 prompt = "Appointment occurs after hours. Mark it private?" 
   If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then 
     Item.Sensitivity = olPrivate 
     Item.Display 
   End If 
 End If 
End Sub
```