# How do I return MeetingResponseStatus?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to extract the new time proposed by the team for the meeting.

```
If objMeeting.MeetingResponseStatus = olResponseAccepted Then
```

says

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

I saw all the properties of ObjMeeting, and that is so limited:

(Application
Class
Session
Parent
Actions
Attachments
BillingInformation
Body
Categories
Companies
ConversationIndex
ConversationTopic
CreationTime
EntryID
FormDescription
GetInspector
Importance
LastModificationTime
MessageClass
Mileage
NoAging
OutlookInternalVersion
OutlookVersion
Saved
Sensitivity
Size
Subject
UnRead
UserProperties
AutoForwarded
DeferredDeliveryTime
DeleteAfterSubmit
ExpiryTime
OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested
ReceivedTime
Recipients
ReminderSet
ReminderTime
ReplyRecipients
SaveSentMessageFolder
SenderName
Sent
SentOn
Submitted
DownloadState
ItemProperties
MarkForDownload
IsConflict
MeetingWorkspaceURL
AutoResolvedWinner
Conflicts
SenderEmailAddress
SenderEmailType
PropertyAccessor
ConversationID
SendUsingAccount
IsLatestVersion
RTFBody
RetentionExpirationDate
RetentionPolicyName
BodyFormat
SchedulingServiceMeetingOptionsUrl
SkypeTeamsMeetingETag
SkypeTeamsMeetingUrl
SkypeTeamsProperties
TeamsVtcConferenceId
TeamsVtcTenantId)

I can't find there the Time proposed.

```vb
Function SheetExists(sheetName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim s As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set s = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
    SheetExists = Not s Is Nothing
End Function

Sub SaveNewTimeProposedToExcel()
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strNewTimeProposed As Date
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objMeeting As Outlook.MeetingItem
    Dim objItem As Object
    
    Dim lngRow As Long
    
    Set Base = ActiveWorkbook
    
    'Define o namespace e a pasta da caixa de entrada
    Set objNamespace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    'Abre o arquivo existente
    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\genascim\Desktop\Gregory Project\Gregory_database.xlsx")
    
    'Verifica se a planilha "New Time Proposed" já existe e cria uma nova planilha com um nome diferente, se necessário
    Dim strSheetName As String
    Dim intSheetCount As Integer
    intSheetCount = 1
    strSheetName = "New Time Proposed"
    Do While SheetExists(strSheetName, objWorkbook)
        intSheetCount = intSheetCount + 1
        strSheetName = "New Time Proposed " & intSheetCount
    Loop
    
    'Adiciona a nova planilha e define a primeira linha como cabeçalho
    Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=objWorkbook.Sheets(objWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    objWorksheet.Name = strSheetName
    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Remetente"
    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Nova hora proposta"
    
    Set objMailItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(Date - 7, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'")
    
    'Loop através dos itens da pasta da caixa de entrada
    For Each objItem In objMailItems
        
        If TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            
            Set objMail = objItem
            Debug.Print "Processing email: " & objMail.Subject
        
        ElseIf TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.MeetingItem Then
        
            Set objMeeting = objItem

            'Check if the email item is a meeting request
            If objMeeting.MeetingResponseStatus = olResponseAccepted Then

                'Check if the response contains a new time proposal
                If objMeeting.MeetingStatus = olMeetingReceivedAndCanceled Or objMeeting.MeetingStatus = olMeetingReceivedAndDeclined Or objMeeting.MeetingStatus = olMeetingReceived Then
                    If InStr(1, objMeeting.Body, "new time proposed", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        'Extract the new time proposed
                        strNewTimeProposed = objMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True).Start
                        'Add the sender and new time proposed to the worksheet
                        lngRow = objWorksheet.Cells(objWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        objWorksheet.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = objMail.SenderName
                        objWorksheet.Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = strNewTimeProposed
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next objItem
    
    'Salva o livro
    objWorkbook.Save
    
End Sub
```

I tried `.Start` and `StarUTC`b.

Comment: You asked the wrong question again. As indicated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75689082/controlling-outlook-calendar-using-vba ask how to extract proposed time with MAPI property not exposed in Outlook's Object model https://www.slipstick.com/developer/read-mapi-properties-exposed-outlooks-object-model/

Comment: [ERROR in objMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True).ProposedStartTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75986902/error-in-objmeeting-getassociatedappointmenttrue-proposedstarttime)

Answer (score 0):

`MeetingResponseStatus` is a property on the [Recipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.meetingresponsestatus) object, not on `AppointmentItem` or `MeetingItem`.

If you have a `MeetingItem` object, retrieve the corresponding `AppointmentItem` object using `MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment`, then use `AppointmentItem.ResponseStatus` property.