# Read Proposed Start Time suggested by the invited people

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, appointment

I am developing VBA code to import from Outlook the Proposed Start Time suggested by the invited people.

I have an error

> Object doesn't support this property or method

in `strNewTimeProposed = objMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True).ProposedStartTime`

```vb
Function SheetExists(sheetName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim s As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set s = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
    SheetExists = Not s Is Nothing
End Function

Sub SaveNewTimeProposedToExcel()
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strNewTimeProposed As Date
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objMeeting As Outlook.MeetingItem
    Dim objItem As Object
    
    Dim lngRow As Long
    
    Set Base = ActiveWorkbook
    
    'Define o namespace e a pasta da caixa de entrada
    Set objNamespace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    'Abre o arquivo existente
    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\genascim\Desktop\Gregory Project\Gregory_database.xlsx")
    
    'Verifica se a planilha "New Time Proposed" já existe e cria uma nova planilha com um nome diferente, se necessário
    Dim strSheetName As String
    Dim intSheetCount As Integer
    intSheetCount = 1
    strSheetName = "New Time Proposed"
    Do While SheetExists(strSheetName, objWorkbook)
        intSheetCount = intSheetCount + 1
        strSheetName = "New Time Proposed " & intSheetCount
    Loop
    
    'Adiciona a nova planilha e define a primeira linha como cabeçalho
    Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=objWorkbook.Sheets(objWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    objWorksheet.Name = strSheetName
    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Remetente"
    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Nova hora proposta"
    
    Set objMailItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(Date - 7, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'")
    
    'Loop através dos itens da pasta da caixa de entrada
    For Each objItem In objMailItems
        
        If TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            
            Set objMail = objItem
            Debug.Print "Processing email: " & objMail.Subject
        
        ElseIf TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.MeetingItem Then
        
            Set objMeeting = objItem

            'Check if the email item is a meeting request
            
            If objMeeting.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Pos" Or objMeeting.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Neg" Or objMeeting.MessageClass = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Tent" Then
                
                    'Check if the response contains a new time proposal
                    If InStr(1, objMeeting.Subject, "New Time Proposed", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        'Extract the new time proposed
                        If Not objMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True) Is Nothing Then
                            **strNewTimeProposed = objMeeting.GetAssociatedAppointment(True).ProposedStartTime**
                        End If

                    'Add the sender and new time proposed to the worksheet
                    lngRow = objWorksheet.Cells(objWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    objWorksheet.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = objMeeting.SenderName
                    objWorksheet.Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = strNewTimeProposed
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Next objItem
    
    'Salva o livro
    objWorkbook.Save
    
End Sub
```

The variable `strNewTimeProposed` needs to receive the time proposed by the guests.

Comment: Where did you get that code? `ProposedStartTime` isn't a property of any object I'm aware of.

Comment: From some place of internet. Do you know any property that returns me the proposed new time?

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide the `ProposedStartTime` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AppointmentItem` object does not expose the `ProposedStartTime` property - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem

Keep in mind that proposed new times cannot be stored on the parent appointment itself - imagine multiple attendees proposing different times. Which one do you store? These times are stored on the per-recipient basis (see below)

The `MeetingItem` object (that carries a reply from an attendee proposing new time) is a different matter - the times can be accessed using `MeetingItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. The DASL property names are `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82500040"` (called `AppointmentProposedStartWhole`) and `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82510040"` (called `AppointmentProposedEndWhole`)

On the parent appointment, proposed new times are stored on the per-attendee basis and can be accessed using `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` (where `Recipient` object comes from the `AppointmentItem.Recipients` collection). The DASL property names are `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5FE30040"` (`PR_RECIPIENT_PROPOSEDSTARTTIME`), `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5FE40040"` (`PR_RECIPIENT_PROPOSEDENDTIME`), `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5FFB0040"` (`PR_RECIPIENT_TRACKSTATUS_TIME`).

You can see these (and all other) properties live in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - select the meeting reply or the appointment and click IMessage button.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code below:

```
Sub SaveNewTimeProposedToExcel()
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strNewTimeProposed As String
    Dim objWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objMeeting As Outlook.MeetingItem
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim Prop() As Variant
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
    Dim myvalues As Variant
    
    
    Set Base = ActiveWorkbook
    
    'Define o namespace e a pasta da caixa de entrada
    Set objNamespace = Outlook.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    'Array com propriedades
    Prop = Array("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82500040",
_
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/82510040",
_
    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001E")
    
    
    'Abre o arquivo existente
    Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\genascim\Desktop\Gregory Project\Gregory_database.xlsx")
            
    
    'Verifica se a planilha "New Time Proposed" já existe e cria uma nova planilha com um nome diferente, se necessário
    Dim strSheetName As String
    Dim intSheetCount As Integer
    intSheetCount = 1
    strSheetName = "New Time Proposed"
    Do While SheetExists(strSheetName, objWorkbook)
        intSheetCount = intSheetCount + 1
        strSheetName = "New Time Proposed " & intSheetCount
    Loop
    
    'Adiciona a nova planilha e define a primeira linha como cabeçalho
    Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=objWorkbook.Sheets(objWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    objWorksheet.Name = strSheetName
    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Sender Name"
    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Sender email"
    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Subject"
    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Start Time Proposed"
    objWorksheet.Cells(1, 5).Value = "End Time Proposed"
    
    
    Set objMailItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" & Format(Date - 7, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'")
    
    'Loop através dos itens da pasta da caixa de entrada
    For Each objItem In objMailItems
        
        If TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            
            Set objMail = objItem
            Debug.Print "Processing email: " & objMail.Subject
        
        ElseIf TypeOf objItem Is Outlook.MeetingItem Then
        
            Set objMeeting = objItem
               
                    'Check if the response contains a new time proposal
                    If InStr(1, objMeeting.Subject, "New Time Proposed", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        
                        Set oPA = objMeeting.PropertyAccessor
                        
                        myvalues = oPA.GetProperties(Prop)
                        
                                           
                        
                        'Add the sender and new time proposed to the worksheet
                        lngRow = objWorksheet.Cells(objWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                        objWorksheet.Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = objMeeting.SenderName
                        objWorksheet.Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = myvalues(2)
                        objWorksheet.Cells(lngRow, 3).Value = objMeeting.Subject
                        objWorksheet.Cells(lngRow, 4).Value = myvalues(0)
                        objWorksheet.Cells(lngRow, 5).Value = myvalues(1)
                        
                    
                    
                    End If

            End If
     
    Next objItem
    
    'Salva o livro
    objWorkbook.Save
    
     End Sub
```

Comment: Looks good, but instead of checking for "New Time Proposed" substring in the `MeetingItem.Subject` property (which will be localized in languages other than English), check if `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8257000B` boolean property (called `AppointmentCounterProposal`) is present and is set to `true`. If the property is not set, `GetProperty` will raise an exception, which you need to expect and handle.

Comment: Do you know a DASL propoerty to extract in the local time? The one above is extracting in UTC. Or any way to transform it? The recipients are from different countries, so is not just so easy.

Comment: Sure, you can use `Application.Timezones.ConvertTime` function. The appointment TZ can be retrieved from `AppointmentItem.StartTimeZone`, and the current (local) TZ from `Application.Timezones.CurrentTimeZone`.